# Jasper Reports : sub-reports are causing an infinite loop

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have multiple *Jasper Reports* (with sub-reports) throughout my application. For some reason, one report (that also contains sub-reports) isn't working anymore. After debugging more than 1 day, I found out that it enters an infinite loop and keeps creating Threads for sub-report filling.

Debugger keeps looping between:

**JRSubReportRunnable.java**

```
public void run()
{
    running = true;     
    error = null;

    try
    {
        fillSubreport.fillSubreport();
    }
    catch (JRFillInterruptedException e)
    {
        //If the subreport filler was interrupted, we should remain silent
    }
    // we have to catch Throwable, because it is difficult to say what would happen with the master
    // filler thread in case we don't
    catch (Throwable t) //NOPMD
    {
        error = t;
    }

    running = false;
}
```

The above method starts a Thread in order to fill a sub-report. Once done, sets `running = false` and the debugger gets to:

**JRThreadSubreportRunner.java**

```
public void run()
{
    super.run();

    if (log.isDebugEnabled())
    {
        log.debug("Fill " + subreportFiller.fillerId + ": notifying of completion");
    }

    synchronized (subreportFiller)
    {
        //main filler notified that the subreport has finished
        subreportFiller.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Once the thread finishes, it gets to the above's method `subreportFiller.notifyAll();` line. Then, the debugger goes back to **JRSubreportRunnable.java**, and so on.

Theoretically, if I have 5 sub-reports, it should create 5 threads (works for me for other reports). Unfortunately, for this case, it keeps creating threads, and my debugger gets "stuck" between the 2 methods mentioned above (FYI: the classes are from the *jasperreports-3.7.6-sources.jar*).

**Also tried:**

I found a [similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843917/subreport-causing-infinite-loop), but the answer proposed there did not work for me. Neither did any of the proposed solutions from [this thread on the JasperSoft Community](http://jasperforge.org/node/527078).

I really cannot figure why this issue appears. I am sure it is something minor as it used to work. Hopefully someone else stumbled upon this and might have a solution. Thanks in advance for any answer. (I know I haven't provided really much info about the content of my sub-reports, but it is pretty private; nevertheless, I can assure you that the contents of the report and associated sub-reports did not change - checked with Git)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Could you please comment explaining why you downvoted the post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and solved it by changing the isPrintWhenDetailOverflows property  of my subreport from true to false
as suggested here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527078/infinite-loop-subreport-fill

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the late reply. I tried that, honestly, I tried everything I could find related to this on SO and on JasperSoft Community but it did not work for me. Currently, this issue was considered to be not a big priority for my project so I have stopped (for some time) looking over it.

Nevertheless, if someone comes up with some solutions I did not find I will look over them. Thanks in advance !

Comment: This worked for me so there must be some scenario that is different, but since this post was from 4 years ago it doesn't really matter, just saying it works in some circumstances :)