# Jasper JRVerticalFiller consumes almost all my memory

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, heap-dump

I noticed that my application is slow.I've decided to analyze GC logs and heap dump. All of a sudden I got this:

[image]

[image]

Some JRVerticalFiller took 3.4Gb of 4Gb heap memory.
It starts from TaskThread which holds JRVerticalFiller, that one holds JasperPrint, from JasperPrint hand - Collections.synchronizedList(pages), these objects are JRTemplatePrintText.

Here is a gc path from TaskThread to Object[] (this Object[] in ArrayList)
[image]

NOTE: I am using JRGzipVizualizer. Maybe this is the reason, I am not sure. As I know it generates and keeps reports in memory.

Actually I don't understand why TaskThread is still alive and why so many objects have been created.
It looks like a memory leak.

***************** **EDIT** *******************

Actually after debugging JasperReport JRVerticalFiller I've found the method

```
protected SavePoint fillColumnBand(JRFillBand band, byte evaluation)

....

while (band.willOverflow()){
   fillColumnBreak(evaluation, evaluation);
   printBand = band.fill(columnFooterOffsetY - offsetY);
   fillBand(printBand);
   offsetY += printBand.getHeight();
}
....
```

And I got infinite loop in band.willOverflow(). It always returns true.

Related question - [Jasper Reports : sub-reports are causing an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954519/jasper-reports-sub-reports-are-causing-an-infinite-loop)

There is a point of view that the problem is in isPrintWhenDetailOverflows flag, it should be false. Actually in my case I set it to false and it works. 
But unfortunately this is a **magic**, I don't understand how to reproduce it, and 
does it depend just on isPrintWhenDetailOverflows flag or not? I have many places where this flag is true, but now I am investigating what the difference between those cases.

Comment: maybe you are holding on to all the JasperPrint's that are generated, check you code..

Comment: Show your code: we're trying to keep our mind-reading and elite hacking abilities a secret.

Comment: I've added an EDIT section.

Comment: I am having this issue as well.. was there any more to your investigation?

Comment: please see the EDIT section, actually, as I remember it's occurred due to `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows` flag, try to disable it and test it one more time